# Using specific column values to create a table

Tags: vba, excel

Lets try one more time. I have a column of data like so:

[image: First Table]

Now I need a code to check through the column, omitting specific values ie. "Start","End","no","*". if the value is not equal to "Start","End","no","*"
than I would like to transpose these values creating a table like so:

[image: Second Table]

For the code, I found this and tailored it to my purposes. It doesn't work as I would like to since it doesn't omit unwanted values just deletes the row they are in and I GUESS it may work for my purposes. Still wondering how to transpose it to a table.

```
Sub Deleteunwanted()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lRow = 17
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iCntr, 1) = "Start" Or Cells(iCntr, 1) = "*" Or Cells(iCntr, 1) = "NO" Or Cells(iCntr, 1) = "END" Then
    Range("A" & iCntr).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If


Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please also share your attempt/code and what the specific problem with that is (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added the code. The problem is I have no idea how to write the second part of the code transposing values from the range into 4 column table.

Comment: Does a * represent a new row? Does the new row occur after every included values? And are the values required numeric only?

Comment: NO, * is an unwanted value, after using the code above I have  now a column of data( my range), now I need a code to transpose 4 values to a row, then the next 4 values to the row below and so on. The values are not numeric onlly.

Comment: BTW I am just wondering, why the negative question feedback, is it wrong to ask for help ????

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. For example, why is the tranposed table four cells wide and not five? There are also plenty of answered question on [transposing tables](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+vba+transpose). See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are still some questions to be answered (see my comments) but the following is a starting point with some assumptions made.

1) I leave the number of columns for the output table in a constant variable so you can choose how many columns you want:

```
Const numberOfColumnsInTable = 4
```

2) I make a list of items to ignore and store them in an array so you can easily extend/amend your selection:

```
wordsToExclude = Array("NO", "*", "Start", "END")
```

3) I store all the column data in a 2D array read from the sheet. This is much faster than working with the sheet in a loop.

4) I loop the first dimension of the input array (`arrayIn`), checking if the current value is found in the array. If not found an error will be raised which I check for.

```
IsError(Application.Match(arrIn(i, 1), wordsToExclude, 0))
```

If error then I keep the value and store in an output array (`arrayOut`).

5) I re-dimension the output array, to only the populated rows, and write to the sheet.

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub OrderInTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arrIn(), arrOut(), i As Long, wordsToExclude(), rowCounter As Long, columnCounter As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Const numberOfColumnsInTable = 4

    wordsToExclude = Array("NO", "*", "Start", "END")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")

    With ws
        arrIn = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn, 1), 1 To numberOfColumnsInTable)
        For i = LBound(arrIn, 1) To UBound(arrIn, 1)
            If IsError(Application.Match(arrIn(i, 1), wordsToExclude, 0)) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                If counter Mod numberOfColumnsInTable = 1 Then
                    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1: columnCounter = 1
                Else
                   columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
                End If
                arrOut(rowCounter, columnCounter) = arrIn(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
        arrOut = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrOut)
        ReDim Preserve arrOut(1 To numberOfColumnsInTable, 1 To rowCounter)
        arrOut = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrOut)

        .Range("C1").Resize(UBound(arrOut, 1), UBound(arrOut, 2)) = arrOut
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: OK , one question though, is there a way ( always is i Take it) to alter the code that  it also ommits a special case - when there is a value "page" let it ommit a number below just once. ???

Comment: If value of page is found ignore the next number and leave a blank space where it would have been or remove that position entirely? And just once? The first time page is found? Or can page be found only once?

Comment: the page can be found multiple time, so if the page is found ( included in "wordstoexclude array") just delete entire row below. Or rather if "Page" is found in the column I would like the code to disregard the next value below ( as in there was no row with tha value).  So to if taking the table above , if "no" is found (any number of times) the "no" and the value below is excluded.

Comment: There is no data to the sides, the row may be deleted.

Comment: This is a bit of a hack (back up your data first!) - https://pastebin.com/09A5imHa

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. So I added loads of words to excelude and initially it was working altough it would mess the rows , now I got a mismatch error :)

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the data and your current code.

Comment: OH right got it to work and works almost perfectlly, but it turned out that at some point after one instence (prodcut name "qwe123432")the output table columns should change from 4 to 3. Also is it possiblle to add a code before that : if while chcking the range and finds a "Manufactured products" value, the above value in range chnges to "400AA)

Comment: Or rather it works perfectlly , thank you but the data is more messed up that I thought.

Comment: you may need to spend some time working out all these oddities in the data so you can address a new question with that information in. A long list of requirements won't go down well but addressing one new problem at a time with a new question linked back to the prior relevant questions is perfectly acceptable. It is also easier with a new strand to start discussing the new problem. And fresh eyes make make for a better solution. I will of course have a go if I see the question.

Comment: I have tried to use your code to chnge the value of a cell above the seeked value but I get an error:Sub findcztery()
    Dim target, cell As Range
    Dim i, k As String
    i = "MANUFACTURED MATERIALS"
    k = "400AA"
    Set target = .Range("A:A" & .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    ' Acvtivesheet.Range("a1:a100").End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In target
        If cell.Value = i Then cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = k
    Next cell
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim r           As Long
Dim m           As Long
Dim c           As Long

m = 1: c = 3

For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(r, 1).Value = "Start" Or Cells(r, 1).Value = "NO" Or Cells(r, 1).Value = "END" Then GoTo Nxt
    If Cells(r, 1).Value = "*" Then m = m + 1: c = 3: GoTo Nxt

    Cells(m, c).Value = Cells(r, 1).Value
    c = c + 1
Nxt:
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This works as well but only if my new row(of the  new table) starts with "*"  which is not the case. Still very easy way to code it . I appreciate the help. Will certianlly use this as well.Thank you.